# Click event doesn't trigger in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

My demo http://plnkr.co/edit/7FQ4ftbhcy2RCpz9hDIv?p=preview

I try to remove play button when the video is played but the click trigger didn't get trigger.

```
<div class="fbVidWrap">

    <img class="plyBtn" src="http://devassets.57square.com/img/video_ply_btn.png" />
    <iframe style="width:100%;border:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=1602992159933648"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('.fbVidWrap').click(function(){
    $('.plyBtn').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: u click outside of the button the video still play and the btn is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this line :
""
It looks well

Comment: which line dude? come on

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
iframe
{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

or add Id to your iframe (ex. myIframe) and then add css like this

```
#myIframe
{
 pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: the button goes away but the video didn't play

Comment: in this case, you must call video play event manually, cause you handled it's click event